# To add Hindi text in the existing PDF without invalidating its digital signature in iText 7

Tags: pdf, text, itext7, hindi

I need to add hindi text with Kruti dev font in digitally signed PDF using itext 7. But instead of Hindi text only boxes are coming.
Anyone please suggest sample code.
Is Kruti dev font supported for Hindi in iText 7?
Which font is best supported by itext 7 for Hindi langauge?

Comment: *"But instead of Hindi text only boxes are coming."* - this most likely is unrelated to the signature. Instead this usually is due to choosing an inappropriate font or creating the itext font object for it incorrectly. As you don't show your pivotal code, we can only guess the problem in your case. Nonetheless, you should be aware that after signing changing page contents is disallowed.

Comment: Yes, with Kruti dev font only boxes are coming but with FreeSans.ttf some characters are coming correct but some are not. Please suggest which font support all character in Hindi. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure which font is best (because I usually don't have to create any Hindi writings) but you should use the itext 7 pdfCalligragh add-on. But as you don't show your pivotal code, we can only guess the problem in your case, so I cannot say whether using that add-on already solves the problem.

Comment: Kruti Dev is not a Unicode font. 
It uses the keyboard layout of Remington's typewriters, therefore you can't use it as is.   You need to use a converter that maps Unicode codes  to Kruti Dev's ones. e.g https://gist.github.com/trinopoty/7983285593384cf74c30db934a6df95e